# 2 errors are encountered while trying to raise 1 of them in an exception

Tags: python, try-catch

I am new to python and trying to learn try and except statements but I encountered a thing I cannot understand nor find an answer to on google. The question is when I run this code, it prints 'Error':

```py
try:
    print(1/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Error')
```

however, in the code below which raises a different error inside an exception, somehow both the errors are encountered and not the one which was intentionally raised. Code:

```py
try:
    print(1/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    raise ValueError
```

the error reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

I cannot understand why both the errors are raised and not only the `ValueError` since I have done an exception for the `ZeroDivisionError`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `During handling of the *above exception*, another exception occurred:` it helps you with debugging

Comment: Use `raise ValueError from None` to suppress chaining of the exceptions.

Comment: Why does your traceback say `TypeError` when the code has `ValueError`? Please post the correct traceback and code.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I copied the wrong error. I have updated the error now.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip but I don't understand why thats happening in the first place.

Comment: If an exception happens while handling another exception, it normally chains them so you can see the relationship. E.g. if you have an exception handler that uses `1/0`, it will report that it got a ZeroDivisionError while handling the first exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general limitation of exception-handling systems that **failure** and **rejection** are conflated: `raise ZeroDivisionError` is treated as equivalent to an expression like `1/0`, even though the latter might be a *mistake* in programming while the former is more likely to be a *deliberate* statement about an error in the caller.  As such, the appearance is that your handler failed to handle the first exception; Python automatically includes the traceback (and type/message) for the original exception in that case since it can easily be more useful than having only that for the “cascading error”.  The comments explain how to suppress that assistance if desired.